# Does CCleaner permanently delete temp files?

Tags: historical

Can temp files/ history be recovered after being deleted by CCleaner.

I used the standard click and delete, I didn’t overwrite the files.

If after sometime, will the files overwrite themselves or be unrecoverable on there own?

Comment: What do you understand by 'temp files' and what by 'permanent' ? There are dozens of locations in a Windows -based OS that are infested by temporary files and neither the OS's own tools or CCleaner decontaminate all of them.

Answer (score 1):

It depends how you delete the files with ccleaner. There is a option for simple file deletion and overwriting (you can chose to overwrite multiple times also) the deleted files. Normally deleted files can be recovered till they are overwritten naturally by the operating system as part of using the freed disk space for saving other files data but overwritten files cant be recovered. as per my knowledge i hvnt come accross any tool that can recover overwritten files. Anyone having recovery experience of such files can add few more details to the answer.

Comment: Also when overwriting note that solid state drives and hybrid drives may still contain content that was directly overwritten (hidden from normal file system access) because the hardware will try to optimise the usage of the flash drive (wear levelling etc).